# python when add lists using array setting elements error

Tags: python

write python program to add list,the first list is a 10*3*11 list(3 dimension), and the second list is also a 10*3*11 list with all elements are 0, add them,use numpy:

```
data_split_count = 10
cluster_number = 3
total_center_list = [[[[0] for i in range(11)] for j in range(cluster_number)] for kj in range(data_split_count)]
print("1 len total center list")
print(len(total_center_list))


total_center_data_list = minibatchkmeansClustering_no_gender(data_list)


print("total center list")

print(len(total_center_data_list))
print("total center list 0")
print(len(total_center_data_list[0]))
print("total center list 0 0")
print(len(total_center_data_list[0][0]))
print(total_center_data_list[0][1])

print("sum total center list")

temp_test = numpy.array([total_center_data_list,total_center_list])
total_center_list = temp_test.sum(axis = 0)

print(len(total_center_list))
```

when runnung, it shows:

```
1 len total center list
10
total center list
10
total center list 0
3
total center list 0 0
11
[ 0.07459313  0.05333272  0.01219305  0.32307944  0.16194127  0.00409273
  0.34603601  0.33625275  0.06253664  0.1693817   0.08579227]
sum total center list
File "F:/MyDocument/F/My Document/Training/Python/PyCharmProject/FaceBookCrawl/FB_group_user_stability.py", line 36, in dist_cal
temp_test = numpy.array([total_center_data_list,total_center_list])
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence
```

could you please tell me the reason and how to solve it

Comment: A numpy array must be two-dimensional.

Comment: Are you attempting to sum the values in each array or combine them into a single larger array?

Comment: to Erick, have not done it,could you please tell me how to do it

Comment: Your error is that you are trying to assign an individual element of your numpy array temp_test with some nested tuple-list structure, while it should just contain a number.
@Valentin No, a numpy array can be whatever-dimensional, that's the whole point of having it.

Comment: to yevgeniy: could you please tell me how to solve it and correct the program

Comment: to Valentin: could you please correct the program for me

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use numpy, it operates on arrays of data. You have to convert your lists to arrays using **asarray**. Then you can just add two arrays together element-wise, using "+".

```
import numpy as np


list1=range(3*5*11)                           # list1 = your total_center_list
a1=np.asarray(list1).reshape((3,5,11))        # converted to numpy array, reshaped to match your dimensions
print a1

list2=range(3*5*11)       # list2 = your total_center_data_list
a2=np.asarray(list2).reshape(3,5,11)

a3=a1+a2                  # your sum array
print a3.shape            # checks dimensions
```